# Clarification on LM3914 dividers

Tags: led

I'm trying to light a series of LED's at different voltages. Ranging from 1 to 10 volts (hand crank generator). So for example at 1 volt the first LED lights up, at 2 volts both the first and second LED's light up and so on. I think an LM3914 in bar mode is ideal. But I'm not sure if I understand how to set the dividers. Is it as simple as grounding the ref low (pin 4) and just running 10 volt to ref high (pin 6)?

Comment: Huh this is weird. Adj pin current on page 4 says 75 typical to 120 us max, but figure 5 graph says 82 at around 25C, and back to page 9 it follows page 4. Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but not exactly.  You will need a couple of resistors to set the full voltage range.  Take a look at the section on Internal Voltage Reference on page 9 for the explanation.  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3914.pdf  There is also an example for 5V on Fig 1.

Comment: Really? I thought it was clear enough.  I agree it could be clearer, but in Fig1 that I referenced it shows the formula for LED current, as well as the formula for the two resistors to produce the required reference voltage.  I don't know what LED current is desired so I didn't calculate this, but assuming we keep the 1.21k R1 (giving ~10mA LED current), then R2 would be 8.47k.  Their example works out to 5.2V (I'm not sure why), so you may be better off using something more like 8.66k

Comment: My bad. You actually got everything.